# Converting php4 date() to php5 date_format()

Tags: php, date

I have the following code:

```
$date = mktime(12, 0, 0, $month, 1, $year); // 1st day of month as unix stamp
for( $day = 1; $day <= date("t", $date); $day++ ) {
     //...
}
```

When executed it produces the following notice:

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered in
>   /home2/wordprh4/public_html/contenido/themes/bam/events/table-mini.php
>   on line 53

I would like to convert `date();` using php5 date_format() but I'm having some issues...

What's the correct way to do this?

---

FYI line 53 is

```
for( $day = 1; $day <= date("t", $date); $day++ ) {
```

Comment: What is line 53?  The code you have is fine in PHP5, I don't see any reason to convert it to date_format

Comment: Where are you using `date_format`?

Comment: Have you checked what `date("t", $date)` actually produces when you encounter that error?  The code runs fine for me even with valid and invalid `$date`

Comment: everything works fine with current code, but using wordpress with WP_DEBUG set to true gives me that notice... so I'm trying to get rid of it...

Answer (score 0):

I dont see a need to do this, but You can use date_format() like this

```
$date = date_create('2012-02-01'); //First you have to create the date
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:s'); //Next simply pass the needed format
```